# Does not contain a definition for "XmlXapResolver" in Windows Phone8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

"XmlXapResolver" is Working in wp8 but Not working in WP8.1 and added Name space "using System.Xml;"

```
public static string GetAppAttribute(string attributeName)
    {
        string attribute;
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings2 = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver()

            };
            XmlReaderSettings settings = settings2;
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("WMAppManifest.xml", settings))
            {
                reader.ReadToDescendant("App");
                if (!reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    throw new FormatException("WMAppManifest.xml is missing App");
                }
                attribute = reader.GetAttribute(attributeName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It does state in the documentation: [Note that this API is obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlxapresolver%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - and won't compile in .NET 4.5.2 or newer (I don't know what version you're using, but it's likely that this is the issue).

Comment: A quick test against a silverlight app indicates that it works there, but doesn't work with a standard universal app, so some cheese appears to have been moved.